# CSS: center element within a <div> element

Tags: css

To center an HTML element I can use the CSS `left: 50%;`. However, this centers the element with respect to the whole window.

I have an element which is a child of a `<div>` element and I want to center the child with respect to this parent `<div>`, not the whole window.

I do not want the container `<div>` to have *all* its content centered, just the one specific child.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Set `text-align:center;` to the parent div, and `margin:auto;` to the child div.

```css
#parent {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
    height:400px;
    width:600px;
}
.block {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:left;
}
.center {
    margin:auto;
    background-color:green;
}
.left {
    margin:auto auto auto 0;
    background-color:red;
}
.right {
    margin:auto 0 auto auto;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1" class="block center">
        a block to align center and with text aligned left
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="block left">
        a block to align left and with text aligned left
    </div>
    <div id="child3" class="block right">
        a block to align right and with text aligned left
    </div>
</div>
```

This a good resource to center mostly anything.
http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: Hum... I don't want the whole parent div to have centered text. Although this solves the problem, it creates another!

Comment: you can set text-align:left; to the child element, to have text correctly aligned.

Comment: @pasine `text-align` doesn't seem to work on an `<i>` element. Giving it a class does..

Comment: is there a way to make this center the element vertically as well as horizontally?

Comment: @GmanSmith you can use `display: table-cell` or `flexbox` for this. Have a look to the link I added.

Comment: why it s so such a problem with that HTML? In android you have to set `gravity: "center"` or for the parent : `gravity_layout='center'` . Just that , and you are done.

Comment: the problem is still there for non-text child

Comment: @CodeToLife what do you mean?

Answer (score 87):

Actually this is very straightforward with CSS3 [flex boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```css
.flex-container{
  display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
  display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.inner-element{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="inner-element"></div>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE:

It seems that I didn't read the OP edit at the time I wrote this answer. **The above code will center all inner elements** (without overlapping between them), but the **OP wants just an specific element to be centered**, not the other inner elements. So @Warface answer second method is more appropiate, but it still requires vertical centering:

```css
.flex-container{
  position: relative;
  
  /* Other styling stuff */
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.inner-element{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  /* or 3d alternative if you will add animations (smoother transitions) */
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);

  /* Other styling stuff */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <p>Other inner elements like this follows the normal flow.</p>
  <div class="inner-element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

CSS

```
  body{
    text-align:center;
    }
    .divWrapper{
    width:960px //Change it the to width of the parent you want
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="divWrapper">Tada!!</div>
```

This should center the div

**2016 - HTML5 + CSS3 method**

CSS

```
div#relative{
  position:relative;
}

div#thisDiv{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="relative">
  <div id="thisDiv">Bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

Fiddledlidle

https://jsfiddle.net/1z7m83dx/

Comment: But it also centers the whole body, doesn't it?

Comment: Well what will be in the divWrapper will be centered yes, but you can put something outside that Div and it won't be centered if you want.

Comment: Exact width (960px) is not proper for most of scenarios.

Comment: @QMaster I know this post is old, I should update it with HTML5 power in it

Comment: There's a good explanation here:  https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 11):

You can use bootstrap flex class name like that:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    // the elements you want to center
</div>
```

That will work even with number of elements inside.

Answer (score 8):

To center only the specific child :

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  margin: auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <span class="child">hi</span>
</div>
```

OR, you can use flex too, but that would center all children

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  background-color: white;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <span class="child">hi</span>
</div>
```

Comment: For my situation (Bootstrap 5 `card-body` element, the first example worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

`text-align:center;` on the parent div Should do the trick

Comment: It's not the _text_ I would like to align, it's the whole element (e.g. a button).

Comment: if it is in the div it should align center, may be a little trickier for block elements.

Answer (score 2):

Is the div a fixed width or a fluid width? Either way, for fluid width you could use:

```
#element { /* this is the child div */
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
/* Add remaining styling here */
}
```

Or you could set the parent div to `text-align:center;` and the child div to `text-align:left;`.

And `left:50%;` only centers it according to the whole page when the div is set to `position:absolute;`. If yous set the div to `left:50%;` it should do it relative to the parent div's width. For fixed width, do this:

```
#parent {
width:500px;
}

#child {
left:50%;
margin-left:-100px;
width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just give the parent div `position: relative`

Answer (score 2):

I believe the modern way to go is `place-items: center` in the parent container

An example can be found here: https://1linelayouts.glitch.me

Comment: Note: Also requires: `display:grid;` - both instructions *(display/place-items)* applied to the parent container. Also note that the parent container needs a height in order to center vertically. *(Works very similar to the flexbox solution (also applied to the parent container):* ***`display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;`*** *)*

Answer (score 2):

after flex it show essay

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  color:blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  justify-content:center;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Element</div>
  </div>
```

and if you set element Center elements horizontally and vertically.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  color:blue;
  height:100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Element</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CSS3:

```
position:absolute;
left:calc(50% - PutTheSizeOfTheHalfOfYourElementpx);
```

You might want to do further searches to figure out how to get the percentage to fit your element's width.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can do it with left:50% to center it relative to parent div but for that you need to learn CSS positioning.

One possible solution from many is to do something like

```
    div.parent { text-align:center; }    //will center align every thing in this div as well as in the children element
    div.parent div { text-align:left;}   //to restore so every thing would start from left
```

if your your div to be centered is positioned relatively, you can just do

```
    .mydiv { position:relative; margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: I don't want the whole parent div to have `text-align:center;`

Comment: why you don't want? Anyway in that case you could use second approach.

Answer (score 0):

left: 50% works resectively to the nearest parent with static width assigned. Try width: 500px or something on parent div. Alternatively, make the content you need to center display:block and set left and right margins to auto.

Answer (score 0):

If the child element is inline (e.g not a `div`, `table` etc) I would wrap it up inside a `div` or a `p` and make the wrapper's text align css property equal to center.

```
    <div id="container">
        This text is aligned to the left.<br>
        So is this text.<br>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            This <button>button</button> is centered.
        </div>
        This text is still aligned left.
    </div>
```

Otherwise, if the element is a block (`display: block`, e.g a `div` or a `p`) with a fixed width, I'd set its margin left and right css properties to auto.

```
    <div id="container">
        This text is aligned to the left.<br>
        So is this text.<br>
        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px; background: red; color: white;">
            My parent is centered.
        </div>
        This text is still aligned left.
    </div>
```

You could of course add a `text-align: center` to the wrapper element to make its contents centered as well.

I won't bother with positioning because IMHO its not the way to go for the OPs problem but be sure to check [this link](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) out, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div element for your element to center, then add a class specifically for centering that element like this

```
<div id="myNewElement">
    <div class="centered">
        <input type="button" value="My Centered Button"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.centered{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        width:600px; //set how much you want
        overflow: hidden; 
        position: relative;
     }
     .containerSecond{
        position: absolute; 
        top:0px; 
        left:-500%; 
        width:1100%;
     }
     .content{
        width: 800px; //your content size 
        margin:0 auto;
     }           
</style>
```

and in body

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="containerSecond">
       <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This will center your content div whenever your container is bigger or smaller. In this case your content should be bigger than 1100% of container to not be centered, but in that case you can make with of containerSecond bigger, and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Assign `text-align: center;` to the parent and `display: inline-block;` to the div.

Answer (score 0):

for example, i have an article div which is inside a main content div..
Inside the article theres an image and under that image is a button, style like this:

.article {

```
width: whatever;
text-align: center; 
float: whatever (in case you got more articles in a row); 
margin: give it whatever margin you want;
```

}
.article {

}

/* inside the article i want the image centered */

.article img {

```
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: give it a padded ridge if you want;
```

}

/* Now under this image in the same article element there should be a button like read more  Of course you need to work with em or % when its inside a responsive design*/

.button {

```
background: #whatever color:
padding: 4.3567%; /*Instead of fixed width*/
text-align: cente;
font: whatever;
max-width: 41.4166%;
float: none;
margin: 0 auto; /* You could make the zero into any margin you want on the top and bottom of this button.. Just notice the float: none property.. this wil solve most your issues, also check if maybe position and displaay might mess up your code..*/
```

}

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center elements inside a div and don't care about division size you could use Flex power. I prefer using flex and don't use exact size for elements.

```
<div class="outer flex">
    <div class="inner">
        This is the inner Content
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see Outer div is Flex container and Inner must be Flex item that specified with `flex: 1 1 auto;` for better understand you could see this simple sample. http://jsfiddle.net/QMaster/hC223/

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

mine would like magic.

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

.flex-container{
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
  .out{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
   .in{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    margin-top:50%;
    margin-left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,50%);
  }
</style>
  <body>
     <div class="out">
     <div class="in">

     </div>
     </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code is always good, but it also helps to add some comments/context around how this addresses the original question.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of ways on how you can center an element, it can be either using display properties or position or floats or margins. But normally I prefer using flexbox as it is easy and simple. I know that different people have different preferences but it depends entirely on the developer's preference and relation of the elements.

```css
.parent{
  display: block;
 }
.sub-parent-1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;  //horizontal centering
  align-items: center;  //vertical centering
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="sub-parent-1">
      <div class="child-1">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">...</div>
    <div class="child-3">...</div>
    <div class="child-4">...</div>
    <div class="child-5">...</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of those answers hit's it. Try this one.
Horizontally and vertically aligned child element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <img width="300px" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/30/Building92microsoft.jpg/800px-Building92microsoft.jpg" alt="microsoft" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex; /* can also use grid */
            background-color: #47472d;
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .content { margin: auto; }
    </style>
</html>
```