# I can't center the image inside the div

Tags: html, css

I try to center an image but not sure what I'm doing wrong. What should I change/add so the image is center?

```css
#img-wrap {
  width:450px;
  clear:both;
  display:block
}
#img-wrap img {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-center:center;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div id='img-wrap'>
  <img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png' />
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: it is `text-align` , not `text-center`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: center element within a <div> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810031/css-center-element-within-a-div-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The necessary property is named `text-align`, not `text-center`. Also, you don't assign it to the image, but to its parent container.

```
#img-wrap { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: @katan SO hasn't let me yet.

Answer (score 1):

Two options, but you seem to mix 'em.

Either you set `text-align: center` to the *parent*, or you set `margin: 0 auto` to the child - and set that element to `block`. This happens because `img` has a default display property of [`inline-block`](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/img.html#img-display).

**Parent to text-align** - http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/w0jecf01/2/

```
#img-wrap {
    width:450px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
#img-wrap img {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#000;
}
```

**Child to block** - http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/w0jecf01/1/

```
#img-wrap {
    width:450px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
#img-wrap img {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: block;
    background:#000;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use following changes in your css

```
 #img-wrap {
    width:450px;
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
#img-wrap img {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#000;
}
```

OR

```
#img-wrap {
   width:450px;
   clear:both;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
#img-wrap img {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#000;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Should also remove the invalid property name `text-center` from the image.

Comment: @SamHolmes Ok i know that let me do changes

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` will not have any effect unless the `img` is set to `display: block`, and is not necessary as you have `text-align: center` on the parent

Comment: You can also add the `margin-auto; display:block` to show in center

Comment: @Andy there are some more ways also to do show image in center.

Comment: @Mitul Yes, but it is not necessary to use more than one solution together. If you are trying to explain both solutions you should separate them in your answer.