# CSS - image over another image , both centered

Tags: html, css, image

I have two images, one on another.
like this:

[image]

But, when the screen resize, the "play image" is not centered (like this: [image]

This is my html:

```
<div class="flapImage" id="idHot">                        
     <img src="images/hot.png" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0; max-width:390px;" width="100%" height="190px" />
     <img src="images/watchVideoP.png" width="200px" style="position:absolute; top:120px; left:80px;" />
</div>
```

And this is my css:

```
.flapImage{
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align:center;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   background-color:black;
}
```

You know another way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: center element within a <div> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810031/css-center-element-within-a-div-element)

Comment: Please, search a little before ask, this question is full of solutions along internet. There are zillions of tons of posts with this same question

Answer (score 7):

Add this property

```
<div class="flapImage" id="idHot">                        
     <img src="images/hot.png" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0; max-width:390px;" width="100%" height="190px" />
     <img src="images/watchVideoP.png" width="200px" style="position:absolute; top:50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" />
</div>
```

Comment: Mark as duplicate is better. However, is one of the correct answers

Answer (score 1):

use absolute and relative positioning, make the main image relative and other absolute.
then write this in hovered image clas :

```
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```