# Center DIV Relative to Parent DIV next to menu DIV

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/ahqamm7o/1/

```
#parent {
text-align: center;
}

.content {
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
}

.menu {
float: left;
text-align: left;
width: 20%
}
```

I tried using techniques from [CSS: center element within a <div> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810031/css-center-element-within-a-div-element) but this does not seem to apply for DIVs with an 'inline-block' style.

Note 'inline-block' is not a requirement I have, I am just merely looking for the menu to float left and the content to be positioned directly to the side of it (with the content centered relative to 'parent')

I am trying to center 'content' relative to 'parent' 
(that is, center 'content' as if 'menu' was not there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some tag issues: An extra `section` tag, `div` tag.

To solve your issue I removed `float: left` from `.menu` and added:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

This will always position the menu on the left and the primary content will be centered as if the menu is not there.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahqamm7o/2/

Comment: This resolves the issue, thank you.

Although, I was looking for something else besides `position:absolute` as once you try to position it farther down (say 200px down or maybe 20% down), you encounter some cross browser issues

Comment: This isn't a good solution as it requires the parent to be in an absolute location.

Comment: Thanks for such constructive feedback.

Answer (score 2):

If you specified the limited width then `float:left` is not needed, apply the `text-align:center` to the .content class so it will align the content center with in that particular div, if we use `position:absolute` the parent should be in `position:relative`.

Comment: Ah! Okay. Adding `position:relative` to the parent allowed me to keep top at 0px and it looks much better and more stable in the style.