# How to align Element to the center of Div

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I need to align the element to the exact center of the div like how it is in 3rd div

```
<div class="main">
    <div style="float: left;"><h2>Home</h2></div>
    <div><span>Welcome</span></div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 222222</option>
            <option>Option 33333333</option>
            <option>Option 444444444</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="main">
    <div style="float: left;"><h2>Home</h2></div>
    <div><span>Welcome</span></div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <a href="#">Click here to navigate</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="main">
    <span>Welcome</span>
</div>
```

click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwkzq/91/) for jsFiddle link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: center element within a <div> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810031/css-center-element-within-a-div-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Comment: You can try flexbox http://jsfiddle.net/cwkzq/94/

Comment: The reason why it's currently not centered is because the two floating `div`s have different widths. Either give them the same width or look for a solution without floats.

Answer (score 0):

Same html, this css, little css trick , use [position absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/cwkzq/91/) to calculate all width of parent, is this class: **.over-all**:

```
body{
  background:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.over-all{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;

  z-index:3;
  text-align:center;
}
.main{
  width:90%;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;

  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height:2.5;
}
.main> div{
  display:inline-block;

}
select{
  //float:right;
    width: auto!important;
}
h2{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The html is the same, I added some styling to the spans within the divs and to `.main`. it uses position absolute to center the element regardless of what else is in there. Doing this you would have to set the height of the parent div though

```
body{
  background:none;
}

.main{
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height:2.5;
  height: 40px;
}
.main> div{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 40px;

}
select{
  //float:right;
    width: auto!important;
}
h2{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    /* move the element half way across the screen */
    left: 50%;
    /* allow the width to be calculated dynamically */
    width: 200px;
    /* then move the element back again using a transform */
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

here is an update of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cwkzq/98/

Comment: @jai glad it worked for you, you can thank me by accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

Insert to `<span>` the contains welcome the following

```
style="display:block; position:absolute; margin:auto; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main">
<div style="float: left;"><h2>Home</h2></div>
<div style="width:1%"><span>Welcome</span></div>
    <div style="float: right;"><select  style="padding:0rem;" class="form-control">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 222222</option>
        <option>Option 33333333</option>
        <option>Option 444444444</option>
    </select></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="main">
<div style="float: left;"><h2>Home</h2></div>
<div style="width:2%;"><span>Welcome</span></div>
    <div style="float: right;">
    <a href="#">qwertyusdfghjfghiop</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="main">
  <span>Welcome</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can do this with positioning...! Try this may be this will help u

```css
body{
  background:none;
}

.main{
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height:2.5;
}
.main> div{
  display:inline-block;
  
}
select{
  //float:right;
 width: auto!important;
}
h2{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css'/>
<div class="main">
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;"><h2>Home</h2></div>
<div><span>Welcome</span></div>
 <div style="position:absolute;right:0px;"><select class="form-control">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 222222</option>
  <option>Option 33333333</option>
  <option>Option 444444444</option>
    </select></div>
</div>

<br/>
<div class="main">
<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;"><h2>Home</h2></div>
<div><span>Welcome</span></div>
 <div style="position:absolute;right:0px;">
    <a href="#">qwertyusdfghjfghiop</a>
 </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="main">
  <span>Welcome</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the

```
position: absolute;
```

Will cause issue on Responsive and Mobile. My solution fixes your issue without adding any position property to the elements:

```
.main> div{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 33%; //<--- Just add this
}
```

This way, even on responsive, your element will always be in the center of the element in the middle.