# How to move div to center inside other div using css?

Tags: html, css

How to move

```
<div class="rate1"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="rate2"></div>
```

to center of div `class="bottom"` ?

---

```css
.bottom {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.rate1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  border: 5px solid #f0f0f0;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px #e9e9e9;
  background: url(http://web.arjentienkamp.com/codepen/tinder/delete.png);
  margin-left: 4px;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.info {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.rate2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  border: 5px solid #f0f0f0;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px #e9e9e9;
  background: url(http://web.arjentienkamp.com/codepen/tinder/heart.png);
  margin-left: 4px;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="rate1"></div>
  <div class="info"></div>
  <div class="rate2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try  `margin-left: 50%;` in `.bottom`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: center element within a <div> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810031/css-center-element-within-a-div-element)

Comment: As the answers state: use Flexbox . Float just isn't going to take you anywhere from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`flexbox`**

```css
.bottom{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.rate1{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    border: 5px solid #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px #e9e9e9;
    background: url(http://web.arjentienkamp.com/codepen/tinder/delete.png);
    margin-left: 4px;
    background-size: 25px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.info{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.rate2{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    border: 5px solid #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px #e9e9e9;
    background: url(http://web.arjentienkamp.com/codepen/tinder/heart.png);
    margin-left: 4px;
    background-size: 25px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="rate1"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="rate2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with flexbox :

```
.bottom {
  display : flex;
  justify-content : center;
}
```

You should also consider to remove the `float : left;` in the inner divs.

You can also check the css-tricks's [centering guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) for other use case.