# how to center align this html content

Tags: html, css

I want my html content to be center aligned, while maintaining the column structure of id `game-inst` 
please feel free to edit my css code, waiting for your help, thanks

[image]

```css
#score-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1B2631;
  color: #ffffff;

}

.key {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.instruction {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
}

#my-score,
#high-score,
#game-inst {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="score-container">
  <div id="game-inst">
    <div class="key">Key 4:</div>
    <div class="instruction">Move UP</div>
    <div class="key">Key 6:</div>
    <div class="instruction">Move DOWN</div>
    <div class="key">Key 5:</div>
    <div class="instruction">PLAY/PAUSE</div>
  </div>
  <p id="my-score">123</p>
  <p id="high-score">786</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey there Tarun. You might be able to get a quicker answer to your question by referencing some of the other similar questions that have been asked here in the past! [Center element within a `<div>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810031/css-center-element-within-a-div-element), [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically), [Center a div horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123999/center-a-div-horizontally-and-vertically), etc.

Comment: If you are trying to delete the question please ask about that on meta rather than defacing the question.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you want.

```css
#score-container {
  top: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.key {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.instruction {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#score-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#game-inst:after {
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

#my-score,
#high-score,
#game-inst {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: left;
}

#score-box p {
  width: 42%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  border: solid 1px silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="score-container">
<div id="score-box">
  <div id="game-inst">
    <div class="key">Key 4:</div>
    <div class="instruction">Move UP</div>
    <div class="key">Key 6:</div>
    <div class="instruction">Move DOWN</div>
    <div class="key">Key 5:</div>
    <div class="instruction">PLAY/PAUSE</div>
  </div>
  <p id="my-score">123</p>
  <p id="high-score">786</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Note the changes in **.key**, **.instruction**, **#game-inst** and the addition of **#game-inst:after**

```
#game-inst:after {
  content: ".";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

Which clears the floats added to the key and instruction classes.

Comment: Please do, if it helped you get on your way.