# How to centre elements in a div

Tags: html, css

I try to bring input fields in to the centre of the page. For some reasons the padding that I have set for the input fields moves them to right and I don't want this. Could please somebody help me to fix this? Here is the code.

```css
.BeWeird_register_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.BeWeird_register_wrapper {
  width: 60%;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #BBFB34;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 1.2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="BeWeird_register_container">
  <div class="BeWeird_register_wrapper">
    <div class="BeWeird_login_wrapper">
      <div class="login_image"><img src="Images/LoginImage.png" alt="" /></div>
      
      <form method="post" action="BeWeird_login.php">
        <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
        <div class="login_form_wrapper">
          <div class="input-group">

            <input class="login" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
          </div>
          
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="login" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          </div>
          
          <div class="input-group">
            <button class="login" type="submit" class="btn" name="login_user">Login</button>
          </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Help would much appreciated. Thanks for in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: center element within a <div> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810031/css-center-element-within-a-div-element)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: As you can see from the properly formatted markup above, you have issues with closing tag order. I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you put `display: flex` in styles of the wrong container.
You want to center the DOM of *login_form_wrapper*.
Remember that `flex-direction is set to` row` as default.

Here's a nice explanation of how to use **flex**.

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Correct me if I am wrong but as far as I understand that's what you are looking for:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wnyu5b6/)
David

Answer (score 0):

To center inputs in your form, add `style="text-align:center;"` to the parent element that contains the inputs, in this case that is the *login_form_wrapper* class.

Also, if you check the boxes in the browser (F12), you will see that the `div` *BeWeird_login_wrapper* shows larger than it should be. For simplicity, just make use of the structure above this heading [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#properties_that_control_alignment) and nest the divs.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help guys. The code was fine. It just needed in the input css code   box-sizing:border-box;

like this:

```
input.login[type=text], select {
    border:none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 background-color: #000;
    color:#FEA6E5 !important;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
        font-size:1.2vw;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can mention use:

```
outer-element{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
```